# Count the number of values that are bigger than 20

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table in my database, *tbl*. In that table I have *id* and *num*, both as regular int values.
I want to count how many IDs have num that is bigger than 20 (**num > 20**). Just to count how many rows have num > 20.  I wrote this:

```
$counter= 0;
$sqlQuery = "select num from tbl";
$finalResult= $databasename->prepare($sqlQuery );
$finalResult->execute();
$numArr= $finalResult->fetchColumn();
foreach ($numArra $row){
    if($row > 20)
        $counter++;
}

echo ($counter);
```

The problem is, that it prints 0 everytime... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any of this. Just do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE num > 20
```

If you want to plug that into PHP and if you want to do this dynamically.

```
$finalResult= $databasename->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE num > ?");
$finalResult->bindParam(1,$someParam);
$finalResult->execute();
$numArr = $finalResult->fetchColumn();

echo ($numArr);
```

Much simpler

Comment: That's working very fine & more convenient and simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more thing - if I want to put a value instead of just writing "20"? How can I do that?

Comment: Can't upvote since I am new but I sure accepted the answer. Thanks again!